# How to reply message to Javascript at some address from Java server in vertx using event bus?

Tags: javascript, java, vert.x

I get the message from client but in case of replying message, i tried many ways but no result .

My JavaScript Code is

```
    var eb = new EventBus("http://localhost:8080/loginUrl");
    eb.onopen = function () {
        console.log("Connection Open")
    };

    eb.onclose = function () {
        console.log("Connection Close")
    };

    eb.registerHandler("server-to-client", function (message) {
        console.log('received a message: ' + message.body());
    });

    // publish a message
    function sendMes(message){
        console.log("Sending Message "+message);
        eb.send("client-to-server",message,function(callback){
            console.log("Received Message "+callback)
        });
    }
```

My Java Server Code is

```
Router router = Router.router(vertx);
vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(router::accept).listen(8080);
SockJSHandler sockJSHandler = SockJSHandler.create(vertx);
BridgeOptions options = new BridgeOptions();
options.addInboundPermitted(new PermittedOptions().setAddress("client-to-server"));
options.addOutboundPermitted(new PermittedOptions().setAddress("server-to-client"));
sockJSHandler.bridge(options);

router.route("/loginUrl/*").handler(sockJSHandler);

EventBus eb = vertx.eventBus();

eb.consumer("client-to-server").handler(sockJSHand->{
System.out.println("Sending Message "+sockJSHand.body());//It prints the message from client
eb.send("server-to-client","Message");
    });
```

How to reply back some message from server ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code sample seems to be fine and almost looks like the chat server-client example application except that your should be using the `EventBus#publish` API instead of the `EventBus#send` API to allow the message to be dispatched among all registred handlers (all clients web browsers).

As per the [Java docs](http://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/eventbus/EventBus.html#publish-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-io.vertx.core.eventbus.DeliveryOptions-):

> EventBus publish(String address,
>                    Object message)
>
> Publish a message.
>   The message will be delivered to all handlers registered to the address.

An update of your server side code would be as follows:

```java
Router router = Router.router(vertx);
vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(router::accept).listen(8080);
BridgeOptions options = new BridgeOptions();
options.addInboundPermitted(new PermittedOptions().setAddress("client-to-server"));
options.addOutboundPermitted(new PermittedOptions().setAddress("server-to-client"));
SockJSHandler sockJSHandler = SockJSHandler.create(vertx).bridge(options);

router.route("/loginUrl/*").handler(sockJSHandler);

EventBus eb = vertx.eventBus();

eb.consumer("client-to-server").handler(
  sockJSHand -> {
    System.out.println("Sending Message "+ sockJSHand.body());//It prints the message from client
    eb.publish("server-to-client", "Message");
  }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. The problem is with my eventBus.js library and I moved the `eb.registerHandler("server-to-client", function (message) {
        console.log('received a message: ' + message.body());
    });` part inside eb.open function and problem solved.